incomplete terniary operator doesnot raise any error in cpp (gcc version 13.1.0)
int a = 4 == 4 ?: 7;
cout << a << endl;

Shouldn't the above code produce a compilation error? Also, the value I get is 1. Is there any explanation for that?
I tried with,
int a = 4 == 4 ? 7 :;

This does give a compilation error.
My best guess is that it interprets the first expression in a different way that might be syntactically correct.


int a = 4 == 4 ?: 7;


This is a gcc conditional expression extension which is not available if you compile it in -pedantic mode.

The middle operand in a conditional expression may be omitted. Then if the first operand is nonzero, its value is the value of the conditional expression

Example:
int x = 42;
int a = x ?: 7; // a is now 42


int a = 4 == 4 ? 7 :;

This does give a compilation error

Yes, omitting the last operand is not a supported extension.
